# IS it possible to upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 LTS version

Tags: 14.04, 12.10, upgrade

is it possible to upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 version to 14.04 LTS version,

Please tell me the steps

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

No, unless yo upgrade to 13.04, then to 13.10 and finally to 14.04. But it's likely going to cause some trouble. A reinstall is probably way faster.

You can only upgrade from one version to the next one or from LTS to LTS.

Comment: Can't you upgrade (not just reinstall) directly from a install disk? (can't remember)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes.

All steps necessary to upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 LTS are provided. You cannot skip an upgrade tho, so reinstalling might be easier.